# Kendo mobile back button in new ios7 style with an arrow

Tags: ios7, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am developing a mobile app site by using Kendo mobile in their "flat" design. How can I make my back button to look as a nice iOS7-look arrow on left side? Viewing kendo mobile demo sites on a ios7 device, a native-look arrow appears to the left of text.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the Icons page, there is an integrated font icon called "details".  To create a left arrow, use the "details" right arrow type and rotate it 180 degrees using CSS.  Finally, remove the border to give it a true iOS 7 look:

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="details" 
   style="border: none; -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest Kendo UI Mobile service pack includes the iOS7 platform theme which you saw on our demo site, when viewing it on an iOS7 device. The iOS7 platform theme is activated automatically, or you can force it using the platform: "ios7" Application option. Check our [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application#forcing-platform-styles) for more information about it.